# How change the color of shading side bar in Marburg theme?

Tags: beamer, themes

I´d like to know how change the color of shading side bar in Marburg theme. Concretely, the top and the bottom color. Maybe rewriting the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Marburg theme installs a side-bar on the right.  You can change the color using the `sidebar canvas right` template.  The top color is given by the key `top=<top-color>` and the bottom color by the key `bottom=<bottom-color>`.  In the next example, the top color is black and the bottom color is green.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Marburg}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[vertical shading][top=black,bottom=green] 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    ...
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```